# New subdomain for each account, Firebase / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I know this used to be impossible, but has Firebase added support for this yet?

I know that they say you can have multiple domains that share resources, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. From their site:

> You can associate multiple sites with one Firebase project. Each site
>   hosts its own unique static assets, but shares Firebase resources with
>   the other sites in the same Firebase project.

I think this would be like example1.com and example2.com sharing the same DB, and not one.example.com and two.example.com sharing the same static files and DB.

Anyone have any input here? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting does not presently support wildcard subdomains (e.g. `*.myapp.com`) and is not well-suited to multi-tenant domain setups (where you need a separate domain for each customer).

While wildcard domains are something we're looking into in the future, it's probably quite a ways out and I wouldn't rely on it happening any time soon.

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks so much.